# ADX: can't see results of ingesting with JSON mappings

Tags: json, azure-data-explorer, kql

I simplified original code to make things clearer.

I've created a one field table:

```
.create table testtbl (dummy: string)
```

Then I tried to ingest inline a small **JSON** document:

```
.ingest inline into table testtbl with (format="json", ingestionMapping =
'['
'    {"column": "dummy", "path": "$.test"}'
']') <| 
'{"test": "this is a test"}'
```

The statement is execute without errors:

[image]

But the table remains empty.

What am I missing?

Regards,
Giacomo S. S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Looking at the documentation for ingestion mappings, the format you use in your mapping is different. You may want to adjust it (e.g. It doesn't include the "properties" property bag). See:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#example-of-json-mapping
2. The linebreak and single quotes surrounding your payload (after the "<|") are redundant.
3. This works:

   ```
   .create table testtbl (dummy: string)

   .ingest inline into table testtbl
   with (format = "json", ingestionMapping = '[{"column":"dummy", "Properties": 
   {"Path": "$.test"}}]')
   <|{"test": "this is a test"}
   ```

   [image: target table contents]

Comment: Both syntax and both kind of quotes are valid. But in anyway I can't get the JSON ingested. Btw, thanks for replying

Comment: I've verified the sequence of commands in the reply is valid and has the expected result. You may want to try that out, and if it doesn't work - include the request ID of your ingestion command for reference

Comment: Yes, it works. I was missing to omit the quotes in my JSON payload. Thank you