# ADX: cannot ingest data with JSON mappings from .NET sdk

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-data-explorer

Thanks to this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150529/adx-cant-see-results-of-ingesting-with-json-mappings) I'm now sure that table mappings I defined are correct.

This works in the **Query** panel:

```
.ingest inline into table pageEvents with (format="json", ingestionMapping =
'['
'    {"column": "timestamp", "datatype": "datetime", "properties": {"path": "$.local_time_full"}}'
']') <| 
{"element":{"class":"CardFeed-title","href":null,"id":"HeadingNewsFeed","event_key":null,"node_name":"DIV","selector":"body > div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > div#spPageChromeAppDiv > div > div > section > div#homePageView > div > div > div#homeContentView > div:eq(0) > div:eq(0) > div > div:eq(0) > div#HeadingNewsFeed","text":null,"title":"SharePoint","x_position":null,"y_position":null},"event_type":{"nodeName":"DIV","innerText":"News from sites","title":"SharePoint","href":null,"role":"heading","automationid":"SPH-NewsCardFeed-NonHidden"},"data_track":{},"device":"","platform":"","language":"en-US","pageTitle":"Communication site","ipAddress":"","officeLocation":"","local_time_full":"2021-04-16T13:38:02.281Z"}
```

This is the table:

```
.create table pageEvents (
    timestamp:          datetime,
    ingestionTime:      datetime,
    clientIP:           string,
    clientUserAgent:    string,
    clientOS:           string,
    clientLanguage:     string,
    clientGeoLatitude:  real,
    clientGeoLongitude: real,
    clientGeoAccuracy:  real,
    pageUrl:            string,
    pageReferrerUrl:    string,
    pageTitle:          string,
    timeOnPageMs:       int,
    webPartName:        string,
    facilityName:       string,
    categoryName:       string,
    element:            string,
    elementId:          string,
    elementTag:         string,
    elementType:        string,
    elementText:        string,
    elementHref:        string,
    payloadJson:        string
);
```

This is the mapping:

```
.create table pageEvents ingestion json mapping 'defaultMapping'
'['
'    {"column": "timestamp", "datatype": "datetime", "properties": {"path": "$.local_time_full"}}'
']';
```

The message is received from an **EH Trigger** (feed by an **Azure APIM**). The message is properly received. I can see it from logged. I verified it's properly formed.

```json
{
    "element": {
        "class": "CardFeed-title",
        "href": null,
        "id": "HeadingNewsFeed",
        "event_key": null,
        "node_name": "DIV",
        "selector": "body > div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > div#spPageChromeAppDiv > div > div > section > div#homePageView > div > div > div#homeContentView > div:eq(0) > div:eq(0) > div > div:eq(0) > div#HeadingNewsFeed",
        "text": null,
        "title": "SharePoint",
        "x_position": null,
        "y_position": null
    },
    "event_type": {
        "nodeName": "DIV",
        "innerText": "News from sites",
        "title": "SharePoint",
        "href": null,
        "role": "heading",
        "automationid": "SPH-NewsCardFeed-NonHidden"
    },
    "data_track": {},
    "device": "",
    "platform": "",
    "language": "en-US",
    "pageTitle": "Communication site",
    "ipAddress": "",
    "officeLocation": "",
    "local_time_full": "2021-04-16T13:38:02.281Z"
}
```

I tried with activating and disactivating streaming injection or defining the mapping directly into code, but no matter I do I can't see any data in `pageEvents` table. I also tried defining *batching policies* but without any result.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Kusto.Data.Net.Client;
using Kusto.Ingest;
using Kusto.Data;
using System.IO;
using Kusto.Data.Common;
using Kusto.Data.Ingestion;

namespace IAI.Tracker.AzFunction.EHTrigger
{
    public class EventTracker
    {
        readonly ILogger _logger;
        static readonly IKustoQueuedIngestClient _client = CreateIngestClient();
        static readonly KustoQueuedIngestionProperties _properties = new KustoQueuedIngestionProperties(
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerDatabase"),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerTable"))
        {
            Format = DataSourceFormat.json,
            FlushImmediately = true,
            IngestionMapping = new IngestionMapping()
            {
                IngestionMappingKind = IngestionMappingKind.Json,
                //IngestionMappingReference = "defaultMapping",
                IngestionMappings = new ColumnMapping []
                    {
                        new ColumnMapping("timestamp", "datetime", new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"path", "$.local_time_full" } })
                    }
            }
        };

        public EventTracker(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger($"Function.{nameof(EventTracker)}.User");
        }

        [FunctionName(Function.ClickTracker)]
        public async Task ClickTracker([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubNameClicks%", Connection = "EventHubConnetionClicks")] EventData[] events)
        {
            await ProcessAsync(Function.ClickTracker, events, async (message) => {
                _logger.LogInformation(message);
                // TODO: refactor this to get directly a stram from bytes
                await _client.IngestFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)), _properties);
            });
        }

        [FunctionName(Function.PagesTracker)]
        public async Task PagesTracker([EventHubTrigger("%EventHubNamePages%", Connection = "EventHubConnetionPages")] EventData[] events)
        {
            await ProcessAsync(Function.PagesTracker, events, x => _logger.LogInformation(x));
        }

        async Task ProcessAsync(string name, EventData[] events, Action<string> process)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events) {
                try {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"{name} Event Hub trigger function processed a message");
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
                    process(message);
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }

        static IKustoQueuedIngestClient CreateIngestClient()
        {
            IKustoQueuedIngestClient client;
            try {
                client = KustoIngestFactory.CreateQueuedIngestClient(
                        new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerIngestionUri"))
                            .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
                                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerAppClientId"),
                                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerAppClientKey"),
                                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DataExplorerAppAuthority")));
            }
            catch (Exception e) { // NOTE: catching System.Exception since documentation lacks
                throw new Exception("Unable to create ingest client", e);
            }
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the root cause of this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see - at least one issue is with your choice of format - you're using `json` instead of `multijson`, and you should switch to the latter.

The fact that it works with your `.ingest inline` command is due to the payload there being different, and complying with the `json` format (a single record in a single line)

From your code: `Format = DataSourceFormat.json,`

From the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language#the-json-format):

> **The JSON format**
>
> Azure Data Explorer supports two JSON file formats:
>
> `json`: Line separated JSON. Each line in the input data has exactly one JSON record.
>
> `multijson`: Multi-lined JSON. The parser ignores the line separators and reads a record
> from the previous position to the end of a valid JSON.
> For more information, see [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/).

Comment: I still can't use it wiht `IngestionMappingReference`, but I was able using code mappings. Setting `multijson` really makes it work. Thank you